# Automate script to replace a word?

Tags: r, automation

I am creating proportion graphs for a list of words.
Is there a way to automate this script so that I don't have to copy and paste each new word in the appropriate place?

In the below script, the word is "research".

```
dfm_research <- dfm(corpus_toks) %>%
  dfm_group(groups = "Year") %>%
  dfm_weight(scheme = "prop") %>%
  dfm_select(pattern = c("research")) 
colnames(dfm_research)[1] <- "research"
dfm_research2 <- convert(dfm_research, to = "data.frame")
dfm_research2$doc_id <- as.numeric(dfm_research2$doc_id)
# plot
dfm_research2$research <- round(dfm_research2$research, digits = 5)
dfm_research3 <- melt(dfm_research2, id.vars = "doc_id")
options(scipen = 999)
researchprop <- ggplot(data = dfm_research3, aes(x = doc_id, y = value))+
  geom_line(aes(x = doc_id, y = value),colour = "red") +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(1999, 2019), breaks = c(seq(1999, 2019, 1))) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 0.005), breaks = c(seq(0, 0.005, 0.001))) +
   labs(title = "Research by proportions") +
   theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could wrap it in a function

```
f1 <- function(corpus_obj, word) {
word_new <- sub("^(.)(.*)", "\\1\\L\\2", toupper(word), perl = TRUE)
dfm_research <-  dfm(corpus_obj) %>%
  dfm_group(groups = "Year") %>%
  dfm_weight(scheme = "prop") %>%
  dfm_select(pattern = word) 
colnames(dfm_research)[1] <- word
dfm_research2 <- convert(dfm_research, to = "data.frame")
dfm_research2$doc_id <- as.numeric(dfm_research2$doc_id)
# plot
dfm_research2[[word]] <- round(dfm_research2[[word]], digits = 5)
dfm_research3 <- melt(dfm_research2, id.vars = "doc_id")
options(scipen = 999)
 ggplot(data = dfm_research3, aes(x = doc_id, y = value))+
  geom_line(aes(x = doc_id, y = value),colour = "red") +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(1999, 2019), breaks = c(seq(1999, 2019, 1))) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 0.005), breaks = c(seq(0, 0.005, 0.001))) +
   labs(title = paste0(word_new, " by proportions")) +
   theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) 
}
```

and then call as

```
f1(corpus_toks, "research")
```

If there are multiple words, loop it with `lapply`

```
word_vector <- c('research', 'anotherword', ....)
lapply(word_vector, function(x) f1(corpus_toks, x))
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I ran the script above, but I'm not seeing any output. This is my first experience with lapply and functions... After running lapply, should I be seeing a graph using the word "anotherword"?

Comment: @J.Doe In your function, there was an assignment for `ggplot`, which I removed in the updated one.  Can you run the updated one

Comment: @J.Doe `anotherword` is just a placeholder.  You can change it to your actual word

Comment: @J.Doe what i meant is that `researchprop <-` is removed in the update or else you may have to `return(resarchprop)` at the end.  But if you assign to an object, it should be ok though

Comment: Missed that, I removed it and reran it and get an error "Error in round(dfm_research2$research, digits = 5) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function" and I used another word instead of "anotherword"!

Comment: @J.Doe Can you run again with updated one as I didn't notice that you were calling the 'research' with `$`.  It should be with `[[` as we are passing an argument 'word'

Comment: I ran the updated one and now i see graphs! But there are no lines in it. The x and y axis are properly labeled. When I run the script without wrapping it in the function (the original way), there is a line showing the data points.

Comment: @J.Doe it seems to come from `doc_id` i.e. `geom_line(aes(x = doc_id, y = value),colour = "red")`

Comment: Thank you for your help. Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: @J.Doe it is created in this line `dfm_research3 <- melt(dfm_research2, id.vars = "doc_id")` which seems to be legit.  Without an example, it is not clear about the reason.  For me, it looks correct though

Comment: @J.Doe I understand the issue.  It is the assignment `dfm_research <-` I removed it earlier.  My mistake.  sorry.  can you try again

Comment: it works now! Thank you! But is there a way to change the title automatically as well? Currently both graphs have the same title.

Comment: cool! But in the title, I am getting "\1\L\2 by proportions" for all the graphs...

Comment: @J.Doe very sorry, wrong placement of input argument. fixed

Comment: No worries, it works now! and one last thing if possible, is there a way to make each graph it's own object so that I can edit them later? Because right now they all show up together

Comment: @J.Doe Just assign it an object i.e. `out <- lapply(word_vector, function(x) f1(corpus_toks, x))` and then call as `out[[1]]` or `out[[2]` etc

Comment: @J.Doe Thanks and sorry for making this too long.  I would usually test it but when there is no example to test, some typos or mistakes cause bugs

Comment: no need to be sorry at all! This was super helpful and I do apologize for not providing sample data. I honestly don't know how for this case